# NMAP Commands Used in Option -A

Tags: network, nmap

I've found that using the command `nmap -A` gives me the most reliable results and according to the reference guide the option `-A` includes service detection, traceroute, and OS detection. I want to do an nmap scan that only includes the service/port scanning used in the option `-A` but I'm not quite sure what type of service/port scan is used in option `-A`. I read somewhere that it was a script scan, but a basic script scan did not give the same results. Does anyone know what the exact commands are when option `-A` is used in nmap?

Comment: Does -sV and/or -O give you what you want?

Comment: not at all. I think -A may stand for advanced options, which would include upping the intensity of the service/port scan but I'm not sure.

Comment: Never mind; I figured it out. Equivalent command for just service/port scanning is --traceroute -sV -sC.

Comment: Relevant: [Nmap Guide - Misc Options](http://nmap.org/book/man-misc-options.html)

Comment: @BhubhuHbuhdbus make that an answer and accept it, so that this question can be closed. Also, link to where you discovered the info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [nmap man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nmap.1.html):

```
-A: Enables OS detection and Version detection, Script scanning and Traceroute.
-sV: Enables version detection, as discussed above. Alternatively, you can use -A, which enables version detection among other things.
```

It's the same as `-O -sV -sC --traceroute`.